# Implementing a simple singly linked list with smart pointers

Tags: c++, linked-list, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Hi I'm trying to implement a simple singly linked list using smart pointers, here is what I have so far, I opted with using C++'s shared_ptr but I read that a unique_ptr would be more appropriate for this case but, I don't really know how you would iterate over the list (i.e currentNode = currentNode->next) to get to the end of the list in order to insert an element using a unique_ptr. Here is the code I have so far:

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList;

template <typename T>
class ListNode
{
public:
    ListNode() : _data(T()) {}
    explicit ListNode(const T& value) : _data(value) {}

    friend class LinkedList < T > ;
private:
    T _data;
    shared_ptr<ListNode<T>> _next;
};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    void push_back(const T& value)
    {
        if (_root)
        {
            shared_ptr<ListNode<T>> currentNode(_root);

            while (currentNode->_next != nullptr)
            {
                currentNode = currentNode->_next;
            }

            currentNode->_next = make_shared<ListNode<T>>(value);
        }
        else
        {
            // If the list is completely empty,
            // construct a new root (first element)
            _root = make_shared<ListNode<T>>(value);
        }
    }

    void print() const
    {
        shared_ptr<ListNode<T>> currentNode(_root);

        while (currentNode != nullptr)
        {
            cout << currentNode->_data << " ";
            currentNode = currentNode->_next;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
private:
    shared_ptr<ListNode<T>> _root;
};
```

If using unique_ptrs are the better way to go for this program, could you illustrate how I would get past the iterating problem? Since unique_ptrs can't be assigned, how would I do the code block:

```
shared_ptr<ListNode<T>> currentNode(_root);

while (currentNode->_next != nullptr)
{
    currentNode = currentNode->_next;
}

currentNode->_next = make_shared<ListNode<T>>(value);
```

using unique_ptrs instead of shared_ptrs? Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `unique_ptr` for this case. They're supposed to manage owndership, so how should these work to link from elsewhere?

Comment: So is my use of shared_ptrs correct in this case? You say that I can't use unique_ptrs in this case, in what case would using unique_ptrs be appropriate?

Comment: @UserWhoseNameCannotBeTyped sure you can. The first node would be owned by a unique_ptr in the LinkedList. Subsequent nodes would be owned by a unique_ptr in the previous node.

Comment: @immibis In my attempt to implement this using unique_ptrs, I did what you just described but I didn't know how to get past the problem of iterating to the end of the list to insert an element.

Comment: _@DerekTruong_ Sorry, I thought about doubly linked lists, for sinlgly linked lists you can do this @immibis is right.

Comment: @derektruong With `unique_ptr` you have one `unique_ptr` to the object, and all other pointers are plain pointers (`ListNode<T>*`)

Comment: @immibis When you say you have one unique_ptr to the object, do you mean I only have unique_ptr<ListNode<T>> _root in the LinkedList class and all subsequent ListNodes just have raw pointers to the next ListNode? Wouldn't effectively waste the functionality of smart pointers since we would have to manually delete the subsequent ListNodes when the LinkedList is destructed?

Comment: @derekdt *Each* object can have one `unique_ptr` to it. The first node can have a `unique_ptr` pointing to it and contained in the `LinkedList`. The second node can have a `unique_ptr` pointing to it and contained in the first node. And so on. (The last node's `unique_ptr` is NULL)

Comment: @immibis Figured it out! Thanks!

Comment: Obligatory watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmxkPChOcvw (includes implementation)

Comment: It's an interesting question, because it really outlines usage of `shared_ptr` vs `unique_ptr` vs plain old pointers. Note that, as the accepted answer implies, using `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` for your nodes is orthogonal to how you traverse the structure, since the solution uses plain pointers. Otoh, it has a consequence on how you use those lists (copy on create with `unique_ptr`, and content sharing with `shared_ptr`).

Comment: @didierc Could you elaborate on what you mean by "it has a consequence on how you use those lists (copy on create with unique_ptr, and content sharing with shared_ptr)"? With what use cases would these consequences occur? Thanks!

Comment: I meant "it has consequences on how you *can* use those list", since, as I stated later on, with shared pointers, it makes it easier to construct lists sharing their elements (imagine 2 lists - or more - which have the end of their sequences in common).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your loop with `std::unique_ptr` may look like:

```
// Iteration doesn't own resource, so no unique_ptr here.
ListNode<T>* currentNode(_root.get());

while (currentNode->_next != nullptr)
{
    currentNode = currentNode->_next.get();
}

currentNode->_next = make_unique<ListNode<T>>(value);
```

Comment: And to clarify, if I instantiate LinkedList<int> intLinkedList; and when intLinkedList goes out of scope, the _root will be destroyed, which will destroy the ListNode that the _root is managing, which will cause a chain of deletion since the destruction of the root will cause the destruction of _next, which will cause destruction of the next node, etc, etc?

Comment: Yes, the destructor of `_root` calls (implicitly thank to smart pointer) the destruction of `_next`, which calls .., until `_next` is *empty* and stops the chaining.