# how to use shared ptr in custom implementation of list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, shared-ptr

I have two questions.
I have written linked list manually to store camera objects, **is the way is right?**
Another one
**how to use shared ptr if I want to use shared ptr to store pointer of objects of camera?**

I have to implement this code without using stl list , vector.

```
//.hpp
class Camera {
    Camera()
    {}
    ~Camera()
    {}

}; typedef struct Node *NodePtr;

// Now declare the structure type itself
struct Node
{
    Camera_ x;
    NodePtr next;
};


//.cpp
NodePtr head = NULL;
NodePtr* ptr = &head;
for (int n = 0; n<n1; ++n)
{
    *ptr = new Node;
    (*ptr)->x = Camera(); //storing camera objects
    ptr = &(*ptr)->next;
}

// terminate the list.
*ptr = NULL;

// walk the list,
for (NodePtr cp = head; cp->next != NULL; cp = cp->next)
{
    // doing camera functions

}
```

Comment: Please follow this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740309/implementing-a-simple-singly-linked-list-with-smart-pointers

Comment: Why do you want to use `shared_ptr`? How do you want to share ownership?

Comment: @Jonathan Wakley I want to use shared ptr so that I do not need to worry about custom delete of pointer. I do not know that much of ownership.

Comment: @Incomputable, _"`shared_ptr<>` sounds like Java"_ wat?

Comment: @Incomputable, it's part of the C++ standard library, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: @Incomputable but that doesn't mean you shouldn't use it when appropriate. "This reminds me of something else in a different language I don't like so it's bad" is bad advice.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, well, I don't think that Java is that bad, but I will keep that in mind. Thank you.